# Codeigniter - Cannot access property started with '\0' error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am calling function form library in codeigniter and it's giving me below error

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access property started with '\0' in /system/core/Exceptions.php on line 85

**Code**:

```
$this->load->library('test_library');
TEST_LIBRARY::first();
```

**Class file**:

```
class TEST_LIBRARY
{
    public function first(){
        return "here";
    }
}
```

However, when I call the function using this method `$this->test_library->first();` it's working fine.

It was working both ways before not sure what's going on. There is no other log messages in error.log file. How can I debug further and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Function `first` is not static but you called as if it is. Change test_libaray.php to :

```
class TEST_LIBRARY {
   public function __construct() {}

   public function first() {
       return "here"; // i suggest to use __METHOD__ or __LINE__ instead
   }

}
```

And then try:

```
$test_library = new TEST_LIBRARY();
$test_libaray->first();
```

instead of:

```
TEST_LIBRARY::first();
```

Or you can just change `first` static.